# Can't figure out why I'm Getting "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" Error

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to do the Roman Numeral challenge from freeCodeCamp.  I have no idea why I'm getting the following error:

> if(numKey[i][0] <= remaining) {
>   TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Here's my code:

```
function convertToRoman(num) {
 const numKey = [[1000, 'M'], [900, 'CM'], [500, 'D'], [400, 'CD'], [100, 'C'], [90, 'XC'], [50,'L'], [40, 'XL'],  [10, 'X'], [9, 'IX'] [5, 'V'], [4, 'IV'] [1, 'I']];
 let remaining = num;
 let romanStr = '';
 while(remaining > 0) {
      for(let i = 0; i < numKey.length; i++) {
            if(numKey[i][0] <= remaining) {
                  let j = 0;
                  while(j < Math.floor(remaining/numKey[i][0])) {
                        romanStr += numKey[i][1]
                        remaining -= numKey[i][0] * Math.floor(remaining/numKey[i][0])
                        j++
                  }
            }
      }
      break;
 }
 return romanStr;
}
```

I have no idea why `numKey[i][0]` would be undefined. As far as I know it is never out of range, and when I do `console.log(numKey[i][0])` in the line above, it always prints the correct value.  Is there something I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Array.isArray(numKey[i]) &&numKey[i][0] <= remaining

Answer (score 2):

You loop is correct .but array is wrong missing some `,` in last two arrays

`[9, 'IX'] [5, 'V'], [4, 'IV'] [1, 'I']` is are invalid one

Check this below snippet. See its undefined one

```js
const numKey = [[1000, 'M'], [900, 'CM'], [500, 'D'], [400, 'CD'], [100, 'C'], [90, 'XC'], [50,'L'], [40, 'XL'],  [10, 'X'], [9, 'IX'] [5, 'V'], [4, 'IV'] [1, 'I']];
console.log(numKey)
```

```js
function convertToRoman(num) {
  const numKey = [
    [1000, 'M'],
    [900, 'CM'],
    [500, 'D'],
    [400, 'CD'],
    [100, 'C'],
    [90, 'XC'],
    [50, 'L'],
    [40, 'XL'],
    [10, 'X'],
    [9, 'IX'],[5, 'V'],
    [4, 'IV'],[1, 'I']
  ];
  let remaining = num;
  let romanStr = '';
  while (remaining > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numKey.length; i++) {
      if (numKey[i][0] <= remaining) {
        let j = 0;
        while (j < Math.floor(remaining / numKey[i][0])) {
          romanStr += numKey[i][1]
          remaining -= numKey[i][0] * Math.floor(remaining / numKey[i][0])
          j++
        }
      }
    }
    break;
  }
  return romanStr;
}
console.log(convertToRoman(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have a typo in your code, the numKey array was just not correctly formatted:

Try:

```js
function convertToRoman(num) {
 const numKey = [[1000, 'M'], [900, 'CM'], [500, 'D'], [400, 'CD'], [100, 'C'], [90, 'XC'], [50,'L'], [40, 'XL'],  [10, 'X'], [9, 'IX'], [5, 'V'], [4, 'IV'], [1, 'I']];

 let remaining = num;
 let romanStr = '';
 while(remaining > 0) {
      for(let i = 0; i < numKey.length; i++) {
            if(numKey[i][0] <= remaining) {
                  let j = 0;
                  while(j < Math.floor(remaining/numKey[i][0])) {
                        romanStr += numKey[i][1]
                        remaining -= numKey[i][0] * Math.floor(remaining/numKey[i][0])
                        j++
                  }
            }
      }
      break;
 }
 return romanStr;
}

console.log(convertToRoman(133));
console.log(convertToRoman(42));
```